# Mathematica QueuingProcess service channels not changing Statistics

Tags: queueing-systems

I am working on a model with students where we are interested in adding a service channel to our queue.  We are looking at the average value of the queue output by creating a sum of the total number in the queue.  With all things held equal, this average will is not changing even when an extra channel has been added.  Has anyone else seen the service channel option not working on the QueuingProcess function?

The code below changes the number of the service channels but is giving the same result

```
Table[{
  q = QueueingProcess[1/6.5, .05, 3, 1];
  lasttime = 300;
  data = RandomFunction[q, {0, lasttime}];
  t = Sort[data["Times"]];
  v = data["Values"];
  (Sum[v[[i]]*(t[[i + 1]] - t[[i]]), {i, 1, Length[v] - 1}] + 
     v[[Length[v]]] (t[[Length[v]]] - t[[Length[v] - 1]]))/
   lasttime (*This is accounting for the amount of time that the \
system has at that queue level *)}, 100]
Mean[%]

Table[{
  q = QueueingProcess[1/6.5, .05, 4, 1];
  lasttime = 300;
  data = RandomFunction[q, {0, lasttime}];
  t = Sort[data["Times"]];
  v = data["Values"];
  (Sum[v[[i]]*(t[[i + 1]] - t[[i]]), {i, 1, Length[v] - 1}] + 
     v[[Length[v]]] (t[[Length[v]]] - t[[Length[v] - 1]]))/
   lasttime (*This is accounting for the amount of time that the \
system has at that queue level *)}, 100]
Mean[%]
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Maybe by comparing `QueueProperties[QueueingProcess[1/6.5, .05, 3, 1]]` and `QueueProperties[QueueingProcess[1/6.5, .05, 4, 1]]` you can get a clue. I do not have the right education for that.

Comment: The QueueProperties that you mention just give formulas, it will provide the outputs if you use variables.  We were really hoping to do simulations and this was the first example that the group came up with and was really shocked it would not work.

Comment: The students figured out the issue.  Even though we only wanted 1 item in the queue, you must consider those being serviced at that time too.  We were able to simply change the code above to QueueProperties[1/6.5, .05, 3, 4] and QueueProperties[1/6.5, .05, 4, 5].  This gave us the result we expected.